# How can Stripe extension create contact sub-type?

Tags: drupal, 4.7, stripe

We implemented the Stripe extension for online payments and are delighted with it. Using a standard contribution page (not a webform) new contacts are created as the basic contact type of 'Individual'. But... we have sub-typed contact types and would like the contact type created here to be a contact sub-type of 'Individual contact'.  This doesn't appear possible using the UI but maybe I missed something.    I don't want to use a webform because recurring contributions don't work with Stripe but they do with the standard contribution page. Any ideas on how to select a contact sub-type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, you can do this with [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules).

Your trigger will be *Contribution is added*, and your action will be *Set subtype for contact*.

The question is the "condition".  If Stripe is your only payment processor, then you're golden!  The condition should be *Contribution is (not) paid by*, and set credit card/debit card as the values.

Comment: Terrific, thanks got it working first go - how often does that happen? The trigger was 'Contribution is added' and the action was 'Set subtype for contact'.  It didn't need a condition & worked without one.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndyClark - glad I could help!  Please check the checkbox that indicates that this answer solved your problem?  Besides that - you may want to reconsider having no condition.  No condition means *all* contributions, whether by Stripe or manually entered, will trigger this rule.  Maybe that's your intent, but it seemed from your question that you wanted to limit this to online contributions.

Comment: Thanks - I added a field comparison condition so that if the contact subtype is empty then it sets it.  Which suits us but may not suit all cases.  Thanks again.